# Swift: UIBarButtonItem only calls action to display UIImagePickerController's interface by holding down the button

Tags: ios, swift

I been reading iOS Programming by Big Nerd Ranch and doing the work in chapter 15 about cameras when I encountered this problem. 
The camera will only pop up if I hold down the camera button. I added a breakpoint at my takePicture function and noticed that tapping doesn’t even call the function but holding does. Both delegates are included in my controller so that shouldn’t be a problem. The button is a UIBarButtonItem is that connected to my takePicture func on my controller.

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var nameField: CustomTextField!
    @IBOutlet var serialNumberField: CustomTextField!
    @IBOutlet var valueField: CustomTextField!
    @IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func backgroundTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func takePicture(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        // If the device has a camera, take a picture; otherwise, just pic from photo library
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        } else {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        }
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        // Place image picker on the screen

        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        switch segue.identifier {
        case "changeDate"?:
            let dateCreatedViewController = segue.destination as! DateCreatedViewController
            dateCreatedViewController.item = item
        default:
            preconditionFailure("Unexpected segue identifier.")
        }
    }
    var item: Item! {
        didSet {
            navigationItem.title = item.name
        }
    }
    let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return formatter
    }()

    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        return formatter
    }()
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        nameField.text = item.name
        serialNumberField.text = item.serialNumber
        valueField.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: item.valueInDollars))
        dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: item.dateCreated)
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Clear first responder
        view.endEditing(true)

        // "Save" changes to item
        item.name = nameField.text ?? ""
        item.serialNumber = serialNumberField.text

        if let valueText = valueField.text, let value = numberFormatter.number(from: valueText) {
            item.valueInDollars = value.intValue
        } else {
            item.valueInDollars = 0
        }
    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

[image: Connections on the controller]

[image: Connections on the button]

The permissions for accessing the camera and library were also added. Does it take a while for the camera to load? Whats going on?

Comment: what is a background tapped? remove that and check how it works. when you place a breakpoint in this function does it stop there immediately after button was tapped?

Comment: @Lu_ background tapped was added to remove the keyboard from the screen when typing in a textbox. The debugger doesn’t stop at the function when tapped. So it’s only calling it when holding down the button. I’ll remove background tapped and see what happens

Comment: @Lu_ you know. You might be on to something. One moment

Comment: @Lu_ unfortunately removing background tapped didn’t do anything ;(

Comment: so tapping is not calling function at all? try to remove it and add again or clear project and try cmd + shift + alt + K

Comment: @Lu_ I reconnected the button to the function and cleaned the project. It didn't work.

Comment: to add function you have dragged from button to code?

Comment: @ClaudioCastro where on the storyboard can I check that? I updated my pictures to list my full connections

Comment: @Lu_ Yes. I option-click on my controller file and I connected the button to the code.

Comment: show us only this button connections, click it and on the right panel last tab you will see it

Comment: It seems that everything is correct, I suggest that you split the screen between your storyboard and the code, click on the button and with the control pressed, drag to the code, it will create the function for you and connect the button automatically. And I would also do a test removing the tap gesture recognizer

Comment: You guys are welcome to download my project and see it for yourself. 
https://github.com/DannyEspina/iOS_Homepwner

Comment: I'm limited on editing my question since I have don't a lot of reputation.

Comment: @ClaudioCastro I have already done what you said with Lu_ plus cleaning the project but I did it again. It didn’t work. I noticed that when I tried adding the UIImageView onto the controller it lagged a lot. Maybe it’s just super slow? I don’t know it’s really weird.

Comment: my answer is based on your project, it seems to work but just slowly with xcode connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your recognizer gesture event is affecting your button. 
It is called first that the tap on the button.
First delete the recognizer gesture in your viewcontroller.

[image: delete recognizer gesture]

And consider using an extension for your viewcontrollers as follows:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}


  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
  }
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks a whole bunch

Comment: Nice to know, I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like while connected to debugger `UIImagePickerController` takes longer to initialize, disconnect device from debugger and it should open faster. You can also try to put opening code into:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

}
```

Comment: I use my phone to run my projects. I disconnected it form my mac and tried to test the camera on the app. still have a problem. I used the DispatchQueue you mention around my present method. What does that do exactly?

Comment: put there everything, with your project everything is ok

Comment: Sorry @Lu_ I’m not understanding

Comment: I added the whole class on my question.

Comment: i mean ad all from that function to dispatch, anyway if it all fails try making app with one button and only camera function and let know if there is still a problem, mayby try different device?

Comment: alright I’ll try that. Simulators respond with the same problem

Comment: simulator shows only library and i didn't have any problem, try with test app

Comment: The test app worked flawlessly. Hmm there’s something weird going on with my code on my initial project

Comment: did you remove project from disk andare you sure that derived data were cleared from xcode? try cleaning everything and run project again

Comment: deleted my project on my computer. Deleted the app on my iPhone. I redownloaded the project. Opened it and went product > Clean. I ran it again still had the problem. Disconnect it same deal.

Comment: I think I’m just going to move on but thanks for your time and effort Lu! I really appreciate it. But if you think you figured out this grand ol mystery let me know. This has  been a headache for the pass 2-3 hours